# Author Full Name in Citation Natbib APA

Tags: bibtex, natbib, apa-style

I'm trying to cite the Public Law given below. When I compile bibtex the output always reads [Congress, 1960] and in my references section is recorded as Congress, U.

I would like it to read [U.S. Congress, 1960] in citations and

U.S. Congress. (1960). Multiple Use and Sustained...

in the references section.

I'm using natbib with apalike style.

```
@article{MUSYA1960,
  title={The {M}ultiple {U}se {S}ustained {Y}ield {A}ct of {J}une 12, 1960. 74   {S}tat. 215; 16 {U}.{S}.{C}. 528-531, {P}ublic {L}aw 86-517},
  author={Congress, U.S.},
  year={1960}
}
```

Any ideas on how I can override the natbib apalike default?

Comment: Use `author="{U.S.~Congress, U.S.}",` (extra quotations).

Comment: author="{U.S.~Congress, U.S.}" gave me [U.S. Congress, U.S., 1960] as citations. I changed it to author="{U.S.~Congress}" and get [U.S. Congress, 1960].